# How to remember different language syntaxes and technologies (as a student)?

Tags: syntax

As a student I have many languages/technologies to learn. Many times I forget past languages within 2-3 years unless I am practicing them on a regular basis.

Suppose on a later date, you have to remember it again. You have to almost start from basic & revise it. Isn't there a better way to retain all the things I learnt?

Live Example: As a student I have to learn C++, JS, Vbscript, Bash, and later on Java and C#/.NET. My side projects are also in PHP.

All these are different in their syntaxes, number of features & quirky inner details.

Especially in C++ & Java there are so many inner details that must be remembered. Like initialising base class pointers with derived class object, different ways of casting in C++, and so many more that are so different from any other language.

Forgetting all this in 2 years is just a huge loss.

How do you remember all these different languages and technologies?

P.S: I had one idea of a quick reference sheet.  Does anyone have any experience of creating one? Is there any place where I can get them? What are the other ideas?

Comment: Even more difficult to remember: the difference between programming and programmers. :)

Comment: I think doing a project on those languages is good idea. Anyone done this?

Answer (score 5):

It's all repetition really. You'll be doing a lot of it and you'll eventually get used to it. Languages that are very similar, like Java and C#, can be a bit confusing at times, but that's where code-completion comes in handy.

You'll get used to it eventually. And every programmer who has to work with many different languages always needs to refresh him/herself after not doing a particular language in a while. There are no exceptions there.

Don't be put off by tutorials you find online, or blogs with loads of examples. The people that post those work several days, maybe even weeks on a single post. They're not super-geniuses who sit down, write their article in 30 minute and post it. Much preparation goes in to those things. In fact, most blogs that have a high turnout, have multiple people working on it. But their names are always in tiny print somewhere at the top or bottom so I always missed that. I know I used to assume these people were just that talented that they could come up with a big idea and write it out in a couple of hours. And many people who were in college with me also thought this. It all seemed so grand and frankly, it was a bit depressing. The idea that we would one day become that good seemed so far away that many people I knew in college just gave up.

Don't be put off by the magnitude of it all. You'll get used to it if you do it enough. Don't pay attention to those books you see in stores or online that say "Java expert in 24 hours". Realistically speaking, count on 5-7 years to become good at a certain language.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "Java Cheat Sheet" and "C++ Cheat Sheet" will turn up some pretty good ones **as a starting point**.  Making your own is a better option though, improve on it as you go and you'll come out with something you're familiar with and excludes things you don't need.

Over time you'll probably get over this problem but a quick reference sheet never hurts.

Comment: Thanks. I would lieek to hear more such ideas. But again making cheatsheets are hard & too tedious. Do you guys maintain these cheatsheets for yourself?

Comment: When starting with a language I haven't used for a while, yes.  It can really be as tedious as you make it.  I have a couple of print outs I'll refer to and occasionally amend.  The time it's saved me always seems to beat the time it cost me to print it out.

Answer (score -1):

Get Cheat sheets of each programming language or libraries